# JSON file list in ansible

Tags: ansible

There is a way to have a list of JSON files, each of them representing a specific user in the vars.yml file in Ansible.

Example:

```
-users:

- username: jsmith
  project_role: administrators
  full_name: John Smith
  email: johnsmith@mail.com
- username: pmorrison
  project_role: developer
  full_name: Paul Morrison
  email: paulmorrison@mail.com
```

in particular I want to design the single users as single json files, for example. One json file for John smith that contains all his information, one json file for paul morrison that contains all his information, and so on.

Thank you

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily solved with the data in the dictionaries. For example

```
shell> cat user.d/jsmith.yml
jsmith:
  project_role: administrators
  full_name: John Smith
  email: johnsmith@mail.com

shell> cat user.d/pmorrison.yml 
pmorrison:
  project_role: developer
  full_name: Paul Morrison
  email: paulmorrison@mail.com
```

the playbook

```
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        dir: user.d
        name: users
    - debug:
        var: users
```

gives

```
    "users": {
        "jsmith": {
            "email": "johnsmith@mail.com",
            "full_name": "John Smith",
            "project_role": "administrators"
        },
        "pmorrison": {
            "email": "paulmorrison@mail.com",
            "full_name": "Paul Morrison",
            "project_role": "developer"
        }
    }
```

---

If needed, the list can be created. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        users_list: "{{ users_list|d([]) +
                        [{'username': item.0}|combine(item.1)] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ users.keys()|list }}"
        - "{{ users.values()|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: users_list
```

gives

```
    "users_list": [
        {
            "email": "johnsmith@mail.com",
            "full_name": "John Smith",
            "project_role": "administrators",
            "username": "jsmith"
        },
        {
            "email": "paulmorrison@mail.com",
            "full_name": "Paul Morrison",
            "project_role": "developer",
            "username": "pmorrison"
        }
    ]
```